# Write a program that asks the user to input an integer X. and print two integer A, B such that X%A=B, using exhaustive enumeration

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to coding and I'm having a difficult time setting up my loop on this. I am not sure whether it is better to us a `while` or `for` to build the loop. I don't know if I need to set an initial value for A, but I was thinking it should be 1, since we are dividing by it. Any ideas? This is what I have so far.

```
X = int(input('Please enter an integer: '))

A = 1

(loop statement)
```

Comment: Your problem seems to have an infinity of solution. Can you consider to ask your question in another way ?

Comment: seems like you asking for ideas on a question you made. rather than x isn't working..., the title is worded verbatim like a model learning course. S.O isn't here to do homework. Saying that... how many inputs are there? one? X? then how is it meant to determine A or B retrospectively. What is meant by using exhaustive enumeration.

Comment: @Seabizkit I am trying to understand the concept of what is being asked. How I am reading the question, I am not sure what type of return is being requested, as if we are requesting input for X, but not for A and B, there will be many solutions for each X. I tried restricting the range of A to be between (1,x), but in that situation, there will still be multiple possibilities for A and B. For example, if X were entered as 5, through exhaustive enumeration, the return (A,B) would be (1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,1),(5,0). How the question is being asked, it seems that the only input would be X.

Comment: @JeremyHadley I have no idea who the above is directed at, what your saying above,  at me or asking what i would like to know. Maybe I do not understand what is being asked. Correct infinity solutions without clarifying what your! trying to do..., seems like you asking  what i mean, I didnt pose the question you did. aka `Write a program that asks the user to input an integer X. and print two integer A, B such that X%A=B, using exhaustive enumeration`